# What does Disgaea 5's post-game consist of?

Tags: disgaea-5

I've finished Disgaea 5 and have been playing post-game missions. I have already

> obtained Majorita and Void Dark as my allies.

And I'm not sure if there is something else I am supposed to do. There are two things I haven't done yet:

- <s>Obtain Asagi</s>
- Beat Baal
- Play the DLC scenarios

Clearly beating Baal will be of the last things I will do, and besides it doesn't seem like part of the main storyline anyway.

I'm guessing that the DLC scenarios will just be spinoff stages that don't really add up to the story so far.

Have I finished all of the post-game storyline missions?

I remember that Disgaea 4 had a post-game timeline where you played as Vulcanus, Fuka and Desco, and I *think* Disgaea 3 also had a post-game timeline. Is there one for Disgaea 5 too?

Comment: Have you completed the Carnage Dimension quests yet?

Comment: @Vemonus if you mean the quests that end up unlocking the Canarge maps, then yes. Unless you mean there is some actual plot in the Carnage maps.

Comment: Well, there is some plot. But in terms of the post-game, that really is it. There are much fewer cutscenes throughout, iirc, but there IS plot.

Comment: @Vemonus so I should go to the Carnage maps and play each of them? What maps have plot?

Comment: You have to play them in order. The difficulty is going to ramp up very quickly and you will find yourself spending dozens of hours strengthening characters, maxing classes, improving items, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the post-game of Disgaea 5 (and all Disgaea games, I believe) is the Carnage Dimension maps. This should take significantly more time than the main quest due to the insanely steep ramp up of enemy strength. Hardcore Disgaea fans would probably say that the real game is the post-game and that the "main" game is mostly tutorial.

Plot wise, there are some questions from the main game that are answered. I am not sure how invested in plot you are, but I think it would be accurate to say that the post-game is gameplay-centered, rather than plot-centered.

As for the DLC stages, they are completely unrelated to the story at all, but they *do* get you main characters from past Disgaea titles.